# How can I hide override methods for Java documentation?

Tags: java, overriding, doxygen

For example I have two classes:

`A.java`:

```
/** classA */
public class A {
    /** Foo from A */
    public boolean foo(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And `B.java`:

```
/** classB */
public class B extends A {
    /** Foo from B */
    @Override
    public boolean foo(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

After generating documentation with Doxygen. For class B, there is function foo (of class B) and function foo (inherited from class A).

Parameter `INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB = YES` only close dropstring.

How can I hide override function like virtual function in C++?

Answer (score -1):

Don't extend - use composition instead. If you do, the method is available, whether it is documented or not.

Comment: This is only simple example. In practice real inherited tree is bigger, and number of functions is more. I really need extends.  The question not about architecture. The question - how can i hide parent method in documentation?